# Honeycomb Status Bar remains dark even with Holo Light theme

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, statusbar

Even after selecting a Holo light theme the status bar at the bottom still remains black. My client wants the theme of the software to be light, and the contrasting black status bar with holo light white background is a real eyesore and worst of all you cant remove this bar either. I know you can hide it but its still black.

so my question is, is there something that i am missing that would turn my status bar into something less contrasting, something like

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.myview);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

or is there a way to make it translucent...

or is that the way it is in honeycomb 
either your app has a dark backgrounds or you are stuck with ugly white app with black status bar.

Comment: Did you put in AndroidManifest.xml smth like _<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>_? Try it probably that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the status bar colour.

setSystemUiVisibility is only used to dim the status bar:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.myview);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I was afraid it would be so, i already know how to dim the status bar, thanks anyways....